# Creating virtual environments for JupyterHub

Tags: python, jupyterhub

I am not able to use virtual environments in JupyterHub version 3.0.14. I have no shell access to the server, but I can use the JupyterHub terminal.

**step 1**

After reading some documentation, I did this:

- installed `ipykernel` in the `base` environment with: `pip install --user ipykernel` in the JupyterHub terminal.
- created a new environment with `python -m venv test-env`
- created a new environment with `python -m venv test-env2`
- run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test-env`
- run `python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test-env2`

After the previous sub-steps, I find the new environments in JupyterHub and I can open a new notebook using the menu "new"->"name of the environment".

**step 2**

In JupyterHub, I select "new" -> "test-env". In the new notebook, I try and import a new module, for example, `hiplot`, receiving an error because it is not installed.

To install `hiplot` in the `test-env` environment, I open a JupyterHub terminal, activate the environment with `source [...]/bin/activate`, then `pip install hiplot`, with success. If I run python from the command line and `import hiplot` I receive no errors.

**step 3**

I create a new notebook in the `test-env` as in step 2 ("new"->"test-env" from the menu), but I still cannot use `hiplot`, that results not installed. If I try and import it, JupyterHub tells me it is not installed.

**QUESTION: After steps 2 and 3, I assume that `test-env` is not referring to the same environment when accessed from the command line or JupyterHub. Am I correct?**

**step 4**

Inside of a notebook running within the `test-env` in JupyterHub, I run: `

```
import sys
!{sys.executable} -m pip install hiplot
```

After the previous command, I can import `hiplot` in the current notebook.

**BUT**

**step 5**

I open a new JupyterHub notebook in the `base` or `test-env2` environments, where I thought `hiplot` was not be available. But I was wrong: the module `hiplot` is available in both of them.

It seems that, in step 4, hiplot has been installed in the `base` environment and is thus available in all the JupyterHub environments.

I tried to repeat the same steps changing step 1: instead of installing ipykernel in the base environment, I installed it in the `test-env`, with no success.

**QUESTIONS: Is it really possible to use environments in JupyterHub? If it is, what am I doing wrong?** I kept reading help pages, but I keep finding instructions with the same commands I used...

**QUESTION** how can I share a set of installed modules between the system python and the Jupyter notebooks?

Answer (score 1):

In case someone else runs into this issue, my issue had to do with environment variables.

`python -m ipykernel install --user --name=test-env` will create a file called `kernel.json` at `~/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/test-env/kernel.json`

I ended up using Conda because it was easier to convince myself that things were sandboxed, but you could, in principle follow this same process for Pip

the format of this file will look something like:

```
{
 "argv": [
  "/home/user/miniconda3/envs/test-env/bin/python",
  "-m",
  "ipykernel_launcher",
  "-f",
  "{connection_file}"
 ],
 "display_name": "test-env",
 "env": {
  "CONDA_PREFIX":"/home/user/miniconda3/envs/test-env",
  "CONDA_DEFAULT_ENV":"test-env",
  "PATH":"/home/user/miniconda3/envs/test-env/bin:/home/user/miniconda3/condabin:/usr/local/nvidia/bin:/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
 },
 "language": "python",
 "metadata": {
  "debugger": true
 }
}
```

The key insight here is the `PATH` environment variable. Because the `kernel.json` allows you to set your path, you can update binaries to point to the binaries in your pip environment. There are likely some other variables specific to pip (like `CONDA_PREFIX` is for conda), but hopefully this can get you over the line.

Comment: Thx, I solved a related problem by your solution.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to achive what you want is by using conda.
Have a look to this video LInk[Anaconda for Python](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=23aQdrS58e0&ab_channel=Academind) where he explains quite well some differences when using pip install or conda install for your vens

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32814641)